# Render error: requirenativecomponent: "rnsscreen" was not found in the uimanager on Macbook M1

Tags: react-native, runtime-error, react-navigation, apple-m1, react-native-screens

After success build on Macbook M1 of React Native app in Xcode 13.4.1 get the render error:

[image]

The same app on Macbook with intel chip builds with out any errors.
I tried to reinstall react-navigation:

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

And dependecy packages:

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

After make:

```
pod install
```

And checked that react-native-screens is existed in node_modules folder, but nothing from this steps is working for me. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

In my case the decision was to add path for react-native-screen native module to Podfile:

```
 pod 'RNScreens', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-screens/'
```

And after:

```
pod install
```